# Populate Combobox with Access Table Names

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagrid, combobox

I have a datatable that I am able to populate from my access database without a problem but I want to add a step in it:

```
    private void button_Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var open = new OpenFileDialog
                    {
                        InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
                        Filter = @"Access Files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                        FilterIndex = 0,
                        RestoreDirectory = true,
                        Multiselect = false
                    };
        open.ShowDialog();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(open.FileName)) return; 

        try
        {
            var con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider= microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source = " + open.FileName;
            con.Open();

            var dt = new DataTable();
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblCustomerAccount", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView_AccessDatabase.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            //get the error message if connection failed

            MessageBox.Show("Error in connection ..." + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

I'd like to add in there a combobox that is populated with the table names then, off the selection of the combobox, the datatable is populated.

How do I populate the combobox with the table names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//

```
string[] restrictions = new string[4];
restrictions[3] = "Table";    
con.Open();
DataTable tabls=con.GetSchema("Tables",restrictions);
```

return a datatable that a column of that represent table names

you can bind this datatable to combobox and set datamemebr to TABLE_NAME

Comment: this gave me a bunch of tables with "System.Data.DataRowView" in them.

Comment: Your question is:How do I populate the combobox with the table names? and this code return that

Comment: I'm not sure how a bunch of "System.Data.DataRowView" is my table names?  My table names are not DataRowView...

Comment: let me reword my first comment:  this gave me a table with a bunch of "System.Data.DataRowView" in it

Comment: k I see what you are doing now, this gives me what I want. I didn't understand your description initially.